# Set is always set to empty even when adding data to it by set.add() method in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am generating a set for selected items on tap of the iconbutton. But only one item is added in set and others are removed.

This is a code for selecting favorite items from the image grid created from a image list. When tapping on the Icon itemname should be added to the set. Right now when i tap on the icon it adds the item in the set and tapping other item it is removing previous item and adds new item. So at all times set is either empty or having only one item.

```
class TravelDestinationItem extends StatefulWidget {
  TravelDestinationItem({Key key, @required this.destination, this.shape})
      : assert(destination != null),
        super(key: key);

  static const double height = 566.0;
  final Item destination;
  final ShapeBorder shape;
  final Set<String> saved = Set<String>();
  @override
  _TravelDestinationItemState createState() => _TravelDestinationItemState();
}

class _TravelDestinationItemState extends State<TravelDestinationItem> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    final TextStyle titleStyle =
        theme.textTheme.headline.copyWith(color: Colors.white);
    final TextStyle descriptionStyle = theme.textTheme.subhead;


   final String itemname=widget.destination.itemname;

   final bool alreadySaved = widget.saved.contains(itemname);



    return SafeArea(
        top: false,
        bottom: false,
        child: GestureDetector(

        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          height: TravelDestinationItem.height,
          child: Card(
            shape: widget.shape,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[

                SizedBox(
                  height: 150.0,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Positioned.fill(
                        child: Image.asset(
                          widget.destination.imagename,

                          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,

                          child: IconButton(icon:Icon(

                            alreadySaved
                                ? Icons.favorite
                                : Icons.favorite_border,
                            color: alreadySaved ? Colors.red : null,
                          ),
                          onPressed : (){setState((){
                          if (alreadySaved) {
                            widget.saved.remove(itemname);
                          } else {
                            widget.saved.add(itemname);
                            print(widget.saved);
                          }
                          });}
                          ),

                          ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0.0),
                    child: DefaultTextStyle(
                      style: descriptionStyle,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[

                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              widget.destination.itemname,
                              style: descriptionStyle.copyWith(
                                  color: Colors.black87),

                            ),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        )));
  }
}
```

Comment: try moving set from widget class to state class

Comment: If you are saying, about shifting class TravelDestinationItem extends StatefulWidget {.....final Set<String> saved = Set<String>();... to class _TravelDestinationItemState extends State<TravelDestinationItem> {..., it was there only, but i thought of scope and put it in TravelDestinationItem class. Its not working

Answer (score 2):

Anything contained inside the `StatefulWidget` subclass (not `State`) must be immutable.

You **cannot** do something like `widget.mySet.add(something)`. This will cause your state to be lost uncontrollably.

Instead have the `State` subclass store internally a `Set`, and use it

Comment: Can you please guide , how to do it?

Comment: @JatanPandya Simply move `saved` from `TravelDestinationItem` to `_TravelDestinationItemState`

Comment: It was there only previously. i moved it in state class again, but still set holds only one item or remains empty.

Comment: Here is the output in console, generated from print in else part written in setState(), I/flutter ( 6959): {Item1} -- Tapped on Item1
I/flutter ( 6959): {Item2} -- Tapped on item2
I/flutter ( 6959): {Item3} -- Tapped on item3
I/flutter ( 6959): {Item1} --tapped on item1 again